# The label is not floating upward, but when i click in the other space of input field other than label, the label is shifting upward

Tags: html

In angular material, for input field when i click on the label, the label is not floating upward, but when i click in the other space of input field other than label section, the label is shifting upward, means it is working fine.. can anybody please help me for this?

```html
<div class="accordion-contentBuy" ng-show="accordion==1">
  <form name='ownerDetailsForm' ng-show='screenOneStatus'>
    <div class="">
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div class="">
              <!--ng-class="{ 'formError': ownerDetailsForm.OwnerfirstName.$invalid}">-->
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">First
               name</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='OwnerfirstName' ng-model='proposerDetails.firstName' autocomplete='off' maxlength='35' minlength='1' ng-pattern='/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/' required />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div class="">
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Last
               name</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='OwnerlastName' ng-model='proposerDetails.lastName' autocomplete='off' maxlength='35' minlength='1' ng-pattern='/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/' required />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Email
               ID</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" ng-pattern='/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z.]{2,5}$/' autocomplete='off' maxlength='35' name='emailId' ng-model='proposerDetails.emailId' required />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Mobile
               Number</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='mobileNumber' ng-model='proposerDetails.mobileNumber' autocomplete='off' ng-pattern='/[0-9]{10}/' maxlength='10' minlength='10' required />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label class="buyTextPadding">{{globalLabel.applicationLabels.life.genderType}}</label>
            <md-select name="type" ng-model="proposerDetails.gender" class="mdInputContainer_input" ng-change="changeGender()" required>
              <md-option ng-value="gender.label" ng-repeat="gender in genderType">{{gender.label}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-class="{ 'formError': ownerDetailsForm.maritalStatus.$invalid}">
            <label class="buynowSelect">Marital Status</label>
            <md-select name="type" class="mdInputContainer_input" ng-model="proposerInfo.maritalStatus" ng-change="changeMaritalStatus()" required>
              <md-option ng-value="maritalstatus" ng-repeat="maritalstatus in maritalStatusType">
                {{maritalstatus.name}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;" ng-if='panCardStaus'>
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">PAN
               Card Number</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='PAN' ng-model='proposerDetails.panNumber' autocomplete='off' maxlength='10' minlength='10' ng-change="changePancard()" ng-pattern='/[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}/'
                style='text-transform: uppercase;' required />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;" ng-if='!panCardStaus'>
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">PAN
               Card Number </label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='PAN' ng-model='proposerDetails.panNumber' autocomplete='off' maxlength='10' minlength='10' ng-change="changePancard()" ng-pattern='/[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}/'
                style='text-transform: uppercase;' />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div class="">
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Aadhar
               Number </label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='AADHAR' ng-model='proposerDetails.aadharNumber' autocomplete='off' maxlength='12' minlength='12' style='text-transform: uppercase;' />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Enter
               Communication Address</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" details="chosenPlaceDetails" placeholder="Enter Communication Address" name='address' ng-model='proposerDetails.address' googleplace ng-change="resetCommunicationAddress()"
                autocomplete='off' maxlength='250' minlength='1' required />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Enter
               Pincode <a style="color: #f7a100;" ng-click='togglePin()'>[Change]</a>
              </label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='Pincode' ng-model='proposerDetails.pincode' ng-pattern='/[0-9]{6}/' autocomplete='off' readonly />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='section group' layout="row">
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Enter
               City</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='City' ng-model='proposerDetails.city' autocomplete='off' readonly />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" style="width: 100%;">
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <div>
              <label class="buyTextPadding" for="inputNormal">Enter
               State</label> <input class="mdInputContainer_input" name='State' ng-model='proposerDetails.state' autocomplete='off' readonly />
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-bind-html="ownerDetailsTemplate" bind-html-compile></div>
      <div class='buyOwnerBtn'>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <md-button ng-disabled='ownerDetailsForm.$invalid' class='md-raised md-primary' ng-click="submitPersonalDetails()">Proceed To Nomination Details</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet is not working .. please fix!!

Comment: place plain `html`, `css` and `js`. Don't use `back-end` `script`.